# carousel plugin and jquery library not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

In my Project carousel plugin and jquery library not working together The link is given below

```
<script src="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

I tried `jq=jQuery.noConflict();`.when i added jquery library the carousel goes blank.is there any solutions for this?

Comment: There is no any conflict between `OwlCarousel` and `jQuery` , just load `jQuery` before `OwlCarousel`

Comment: thanks @Pedram its works fine.

Answer (score 1):

you write the min js above and then write owl carousel js like below

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="plugins/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```